# Is it possible to specify specific flags/define for DLL/SO build?

Tags: c++, dll, build-automation, automake, libtool

How can I specify some unique flags for DLL only builds. By default libtool adds `-DDLL_EXPORT` which is fine for most projects that follow GNU conventions, but if I work, for example, with Boost I may need to specify for my library flags: `-DDLL_EXPORT -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` for DLL only builds, also sometimes I want conditional builds so I need some specific defines for DLL/SO build.

Unfortunately I can't find a way how to do this with libtool, what flags should I use?

**P.S.:** Don't even try to suggest to move to CMake.

**Example:**

I use library foo that links to bar and requires -DBAR_EXPORTS to get symbols for dynamic library only.

Is there something like

```
 libfoo_la_dynamic_CXXFLAGS = -DBAR_EXPORTS
```

**Anybody?**

**Alternative Solution:** (quite ugly)

Create a file `defines.h

```
#if defined(PIC) || defined(DLL_EXPORT)
#define BAR_EXPORTS
#endif
```

And then:

```
 libfoo_la_CXXFLAGS += -include defines.h
```

Ugly but should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable building shared library by default with

```
LT_INIT([disable-shared])
```

then you can use `AM_CONDITIONAL` combined with `--enabled-shared` and set the extra definitions if shared library is explicitly requested. IOW, enable building static or shared, but not both at the same time.

Comment: @Artyom Perhaps there is, but I'm not aware of it. I use Autotools only on Unix and I avoid using it on Windows for building DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Not that pretty, but could you use a [conditional](http://sources.redhat.com/automake/automake.html#Usage-of-Conditionals) to check if DLL_EXPORT is defined and if it is define the others you need?

I'm not that good with autotools, I prefer CMake but you seem quite against that.

Comment: `am_conditional` is project global, but, generally when you build with libtool you build both static and shared library. So this is not real solution.